# Angular 4 Unit Test cannot find name alert, confirm, event

Tags: unit-testing, angular-cli, angular

Running ng test in angular-cli with Angular 4.0.0 gives errors like:

```
Cannot find name 'alert'
Cannot find name 'confirm'
Cannot find name 'Event'
```

This wasn't happening with Angular 2. Looks like something is missing here but what is it?

ng serve and build work fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix the issue I have generated a new project using latest @angular/cli and then compared and updated all of my tsconfg files to the current format.

Comment: So what exactly was the difference?

Answer (score 3):

In my case this was solved by adding `"dom`" to the `"lib"` array in tsconfig. I had a tsconfig.app.json that was used for building the app normally, and a tsconfig.spec.json that was just used for unit testing. This latter one was missing `"dom"`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing **typings.d.ts** according to latest cli [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update#typingsdts).

> src/typings.d.ts:

**Old:**

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: {
  id: string;
};
```

**New:**

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}
```